# Reversed cumulative start date calculation with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is structured as follows:

```
   Group    LT         Start
0      A     5           NaT
1      A    10           NaT
2      A     0    20-03-2024
3      B     3           NaT
4      B     0    04-03-2024
5      C     2           NaT
6      C     4           NaT
7      C     0    04-04-2024
8      C     0    10-04-2024
9      C     0    24-04-2024
```

For each group as defined in column `Group` I need to calculate the start date from bottom to top, only of rows where value in `Start` is `NaT`. This means: the first row within a group where `Start` is not `NaT` == starting point for backwards cumulative calculation. As shown in example data, this differs for each group. The calculation should stop for each group when a new group starts. The last row of each group always has a datetime value in `Start`, so there is always a start point for the calculation. The value in `LT` represents business days, so weekends should be skipped. Hence, required output is:

```
   Group    LT         Start
0      A     5    28-02-2024
1      A    10    06-03-2024
2      A     0    20-03-2024
3      B     3    28-02-2024
4      B     0    04-03-2024
5      C     2    27-03-2024
6      C     4    29-03-2024
7      C     0    04-04-2024
8      C     0    10-04-2024
9      C     0    24-04-2024
```

The code below works according to the groups and only looks at rows with `NaT` values. However it does not ignore the weekends.

```
groups = df.groupby('Group')
nan_start_mask = df['Start'].isna()
df['Start'] = groups['Start'].bfill()
start_date = df['Start'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['LT'], unit='D')
df.loc[nan_start_mask, 'Start'] = start_date[nan_start_mask]
```

The code below also works for the groups and also business days, however it overwrites values in `Start` and only keeps the last row of each group intact.

```
s = (df.loc[::-1, LT'].groupby(df['Group']).cumsum().apply(pd.offsets.BusinessDay))
g = df.groupby('Group')
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(g['Start'].transform('first').sub(s))
```

It is essential to not overwrite existing `Start` values as for these rows `LT` values are not usable. I am struggling to combine the method of the last code, with the functionality of only looking at NaT rows of the first code. Any suggestions?

**The specific difference with my previous question is:**

- Previous question: calculation always started at the last row of the group, first result to be printed was always second to last.
- Current question: For each group, it has to find the first row with a start value and use this as a starting point for the calculation.

Comment: I wonder why you opened a new question when you completely *ignored* the answer from your previous one.

Comment: @Timeless I had forgotten about this answer, was about to answer something similar

Comment: @Prmake maybe address your concerns in the other question, I'm happy to update if needed

Comment: I found out about the other question because OP used a lazy `groupby` (*which is a moz'way*) :p

Comment: The code from my previous question I included (somewhat modified) as second code. The problem is that this code starts with the second to last row of each group and overwrites the already existing 'Start' values. So in my data example that is fine for groups A and B, but not C. The start values of index 7 and 8 will be overwritten.